# Is it possible to read a query into an 'universal' object?

Tags: oracle, plsql

I would like to have a table with selects. Something like this:

```
Row 1
SELECT 
   num1,
   num2,
   string1
FROM abc;

Row 2
SELECT 
   num1,
   string1
FROM xyz;
```

I would like to execute these selects. I think there is no different way than reading them from table and executing with `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE`. Or am I wrong?
Now I would like to read the entries into any data structure.
Is it possible to read them into some 'universal' object or any data structure?
I don't know how many fields I will have and of which type. The type problem could be solved so, that I will convert everything to varchar for example. Or is there any better solution? And how can I solve the problem of number of fields?
The goal is to write these entries to a file.

Comment: Have you looked into [dbms_sql](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/lnpls/dynamic-sql.html#GUID-4E1FD47B-7E1A-42E9-9792-210F13C75A1B)?

Comment: Universal object may be an XML document, which creates a lot of overhead, but query result may easily be serialized with [`dbms_xmlgen`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/arpls/DBMS_XMLGEN.html#GUID-E4BCC071-97A5-4AE3-B2C8-BDF089C3F067) package.

Comment: I want rather a universal cursor. So that I can modify  the results in a program and write a csv file at the end.

Comment: Until now I only found, that I can execute the 'universal'  cursor but I still haven't found the possibility to read the entries in a variable, loop through the cursor and modify these variables.

Comment: Look for examples which use `decribe_columns` and `column_value` - sorry, don't have time to put an example together at the moment.

Comment: If "the goal is to write these entries to a file" then are you sure you need a 'universal' object? If you focus on a way to write any cursor to csv format, you might get a solution without universal objects.

Comment: The goal is to get a query from a table and write it to csv. What do you suggest?